# flutter - how to submit textformfield to a sign up button?

Tags: flutter, validation, dart, textformfield

I have 4 textformfield. One for email, username, and 2 password fields. They all have proper validation. Except for the password field where I want to check if the 2 passwords are the same. Not sure how to do that part. I also have a register button
I want to gather input from those 4 textform field and send it to the register button to sign up a new account using firebase. How do i get my register button to accept those form outputs?

[screenshot of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPZBe.png)

Comment: Paste your code for the Form that you have created.

Answer (score 1):

you can use variable assigned to each textformfield as a value property and assign new value to them with onchanged method existing in textformfield. Something like this:

> TextFormField(   value: _password,   onchange: (val) {   _password =
> val;   } )

Or use controller for textformfield and get their value on submit:

> TextFormField(   controller: _controller )

Now, on button you can execute your functionality or call a method which has the functionality:

> RaisedButton (   onPressed: () {  ///  Getting data from the
> controller attached to textformfield   String password =
> _controller.text;
>
> ////   Firebase auth code here. } )

Answer (score 0):

You can add controller to four of your `TextField`.

```
final _dataController = TextEditingController();
```

When submit button is clicked, you can get the value by this

```
String data = _dataController.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

For checking if both the password and confirm passwords are the same u may have to add a conditional part in the validation of the form.

You can register a user like this:

```
String _email;
String _password; //add these two to the validation and set the value state = to these fields respectively.

try {
         UserCredential userCredential = await 
         FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
         email: _email,
         password: _password
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

For more information refer [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage)